# Getting "NoSuchElementException" when using "@AndroidFindBy()" to locate an element

Tags: java, selenium, appium-android

Setup is as:
Android Emulator Version: Nexus 5X API 27, Android 8.1 (Google Play) and Browser: Google Chrome

My declarations are as below:

```
    @AndroidFindBy(id = "user_login")
    WebElement user_login;

    @AndroidFindBy(id = "user_pass")
    WebElement user_pass;

    @AndroidFindBy(id = "wp-submit")
    WebElement wp_submit;

    String url = "http://demosite.center/wordpress/wp-login.php";
```

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Log In">
```

Method which uses the WebElements

```
    public void enter(String usr, String pwd) {
        try {
            user_login.sendKeys(usr);
            System.out.println("entered username");
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            user_pass.sendKeys(pwd);
            System.out.println("entered password");
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            wp_submit.click();
            System.out.println("clicked login button");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The exception which I am getting is:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.3
May 08, 2019 11:31:22 AM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
entered username
entered password
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Can't locate an element by this strategy: by id or name "wp_submit"
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.findElement(AppiumElementLocator.java:126)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.interceptors.InterceptorOfASingleElement.intercept(InterceptorOfASingleElement.java:60)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b598166c.click(<generated>)
    at com.pages.DemoSiteWpLoginPage.enter(DemoSiteWpLoginPage.java:41)
    at com.tests.LoginTest.demoAutTest(LoginTest.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator$WaitingFunction@3e2059ae (tried for 1 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:315)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:283)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.waitFor(AppiumElementLocator.java:99)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.findElement(AppiumElementLocator.java:119)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"wp_submit"}
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z'
System info: host: 'M5-D-BZCJQM2', ip: '10.222.46.14', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities {browserName: Chrome, databaseEnabled: false, desired: {browserName: Chrome, deviceName: emulator-5554, newCommandTimeout: 100, platformName: Android, platformVersion: 8.1}, deviceManufacturer: Google, deviceModel: Android SDK built for x86, deviceName: emulator-5554, deviceScreenSize: 1080x1920, deviceUDID: emulator-5554, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: true, newCommandTimeout: 100, platform: LINUX, platformName: Android, platformVersion: 8.1.0, takesScreenshot: true, warnings: {}, webStorageEnabled: false}
Session ID: fb0e8048-7572-4f4d-bc07-b5ac0a219c08
*** Element info: {Using=name, value=wp_submit}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:231)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:322)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:62)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByName(RemoteWebDriver.java:400)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElementByName(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:118)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementByName(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElementByName(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName.findElement(By.java:284)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ByIdOrName.findElement(ByIdOrName.java:50)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:314)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:58)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.bys.ContentMappedBy.findElement(ContentMappedBy.java:50)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:314)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:58)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator.lambda$0(AppiumElementLocator.java:120)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator$WaitingFunction.apply(AppiumElementLocator.java:172)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocator$WaitingFunction.apply(AppiumElementLocator.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:260)
    ... 31 more
PASSED: demoAutTest

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

My assumption: The script is using the variable name of WebElement to locate the element on the UI instead of the locator which I am passing in the @AndroidFindBy.

Please let me know if more information is required from my end.

EDIT 1:

```
@AndroidFindBy(id = "user_login")
WebElement userName;
```

*above was not working*

```
@AndroidFindBy(id = "user_login")
WebElement user_login;
```

*after changing the variable name to that of what is there for the id, above is working*

Before posting the question here, I had google'd and refered below references, but they have slightly different implementation of @AndroidFindBy or have not used this approach.

[How to fix "Can't locate an element by this strategy: Locator map:"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418628/how-to-fix-cant-locate-an-element-by-this-strategy-locator-map)

https://discuss.appium.io/t/nosuchelementexception-when-element-is-actually-present/18711/30

Comment: Did you change the variable name and tried ? and how are u selecting the enter button ?

Comment: If your assumption is true then that's a bug

Comment: @MateMrše : OP should have checked before posting here. I don't understand this, He want us to do checking ?

Comment: @LokeshwarTailor "wp-submit" doesn't seem consistent with other ids. Are you sure that error stack trace is caused by that code (there was no editing the code after running it)?

Comment: @cruisepandey I don't want you to do the checking. I am actually new to Appium and am not getting how to resolve it. If you don't want to help, then just ignore, simple.

As far as your suggestion of changing the variable name, I tried combinations of changing the variable name to that of what I am passing to @AndroidBy() and I have added my observations at the end of my question

Comment: @MateMrše I believe so, that is what is causing the problem. Yes, the error stack trace which I have put up is the one for which the script is failing. No editing was done after code running.

Comment: @LokeshwarTailor : Don't be rude, it's your responsibility to check everything before posting here which you didn't do it at first place. Now you have checked and edited the question. I gave my time reading your question, and if it is not appropriate , I would definitely criticise it.

Comment: @LokeshwarTailor Please, add the code of the failing test, as well. Also, HTML of the element in question would be helpful.

Comment: @MateMrše added the required info in the question description.

Comment: @LokeshwarTailor Try changing `@AndroidFindBy(id = "wp-submit")` to `@AndroidFindBy(css = "#wp-submit")`.

Comment: @MateMrše `@AndroidFindBy(css="#wp-submit")` gives compilation error. It only accepts `accessibility, id, name, class name, tag and xpath` [AndroidFindBy doc reference] (https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/pagefactory/AndroidFindBy.html). I have tried with `name, xpath`, it's giving the same exception.

Comment: Ok, try `@AndroidFindBy(xpath="//*[@id='wp-submit']")`

Comment: Failed with `@AndroidFindBy(xpath="//*[@id='wp-submit']")`. Before posting the question here, I had tried with `@AndroidFindBy(xpath="//input[@id='wp-submit']")` and that too had failed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193027/discussion-between-lokeshwar-tailor-and-mate-mrse).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [`@AndroidFindBy` annotation documentation](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/pagefactory/AndroidFindBy.html)

> Used to mark a field on a Page Object to indicate an alternative mechanism for locating the element or a list of elements. Used in conjunction with PageFactory this allows users to quickly and easily create PageObjects. **using Android UI selectors, accessibility, id, name, class name, tag and xpath**

It means that you can use this Annotation in order to access **Android UI elements** like browser "Back" and "Reload" buttons

Given you're automating a web page in Chrome browser you should replace all occurrences of the `@AndroidFindBy` with [`@FindBy` from org.openqa.selenium.support package](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBy.html)

More information:

- [Selenium - Page Object Design Pattern](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#page-object-design-pattern)
- [Design Patterns - Page Object Model](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Design+Patterns+-+Page+Object+Model)